# Charger Delta Electronics ESR-48/40A E Voltage and Current Adjustments

Tags: charger, delta

Does anybody know how to change (i.e. program) the output voltage and limit the output current in the Delta Electronics ESR-48/40AE charger? The following web pages: [this one](http://www.sanmpower.com/display.php?id=80) and the [next one](http://www.sanmpower.com/display.php?id=78) have pinouts for two other Delta chargers that seem to match my charger. I'm linking these images directly here:

Delta ESR-48V/56AC 54V(54V~59V)  50A
[image: Delta ESR-48V/56AC 54V(54V~59V) 50A Pinout]

Delta ESR-48/30G C 54V(43V~58V)  32.22A
[image: Delta ESR-48/30G C 54V(43V~58V) 32.22A Pinout]

I have attached pictures of my charger and technical specifications from a two page fact sheet PDF.
[image: Label]
[image: Connector]
[image: Innards]
[image: Technical specifications]

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/6411-Canbus-v4.pdf

```
The BMS uses the following link level spec.
1) bitrate; 500Kbps
2) Packet Rate; 50milliseconds
3) packet; standard format
4) ID; 04D
```

(just from a web search not 1st hand knowing)

[Make DIY project](https://www.mictronics.de/projects/usb-can-bus/comment-page-1/)  You can search for buy options.